# Very slow query during update document

Tags: mongodb, insert, updates

I started with MongoDB and I have following problem. I have 3500 entities that i get from external API (new entities, deleted entities, changed entities). If I use insert_many, everything is fast and good, but I must use update with upsert.

Inserting or updating entities takes a long time (500 entities about 10 second).

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

```
    for i in categories:
        await collection.update_one(
            {'id:': i['id']},
            {'$set': {'data': i}},
            upsert=True
        )
```

```
db.collection.createIndex({"id": 1})
```

Comment: Use update_many in order to speed up the db operation.

Comment: But update_many only update multiple document which meet the condition. I want update 500 different documents.

Comment: Ok, sorry for wasting your time. Solution is bulk update. Thanks